# Why/how is $au_x + bu_y$ the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{V} = (a, b) = a \mathbf{i} + b \mathbf{j}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I am currently studying the textbook *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*, second edition, by Walter A. Strauss. Chapter **1.2 First-Order Linear Equations** says the following:

> Let us solve
> $$au_x + bu_y = 0,$$
> where $a$ and $b$ are constants not both zero.
>
> **Geometric Method** The quantity $au_x + bu_y$ is the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{V} = (a, b) = a \mathbf{i} + b \mathbf{j}$. It must always be zero. This means that $u(x, y)$ must be constant in the direction of $\mathbf{V}$.

The author states that the quantity $au_x + bu_y$ is the directional derivative of $u$ in the directions of the vector $\mathbf{V} = (a, b) = a \mathbf{i} + b \mathbf{j}$, but offers no justification. Why/how is the quantity $au_x + bu_y$ the directional derivative of $u$ in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{V} = (a, b) = a \mathbf{i} + b \mathbf{j}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because,

$$ D_{V}(u) = V \cdot \nabla u =  (a, b) \cdot (u_x, u_y) = a u_x + bu_y $$

Comment: Maybe noted for directioncal derivative in other basis, it won't be as simple as multiplying components, you'd have to account for the metric tensor to take dot products

Comment: 1. Please use the same notation as in the original question, so that your point is clear. 2. Your answer should reflect the difficulty level at which the question is asked, which is obviously far below the level of metric tensors, so I'm not sure why you're complicating things by introducing/discussing them.

Comment: @ThePointer I mean, it's not really required for the case you're dealing with but for like more complicated cases, just so you don't get stuck, I wanted you to know there is such a thing.  Sorry for not keeping the notation consistent, I just wrote a fast answer.

Comment: All good. The way you have laid it out makes the concept clear to me. Thanks for taking the time to clarify!

Comment: I would suggest you check out Gauge Fields & Knots and gravity from page-23, it has some similar concepts of seeing how vector fields act on functions. It may build more insight for you. @ThePointer

Comment: I'll take a look at it, but the textbook sounds super advanced.

Comment: It's written for physicists so

Answer (score 0):

It's really just a special case of the chain rule. The directional derivative measures how a function changes when going in the specified direction. The "direction" being along the line $\mathbf{r}_0+t\mathbf V$. So it's the derivative of the function $u(\mathbf r_0+t\mathbf V)$ at $t=0$. But this function is a composition of $u(\mathbf r)$ and $\mathbf r_0+t\mathbf V$. If you apply the chain rule, you will get that the derivative is $(\nabla u^T) \mathbf V$, which, when written in coordinates, is exactly your formula.

Comment: Perhaps you should demonstrate/show the mathematics that your answer is referring to.

Comment: It's a very direct application. The derivative of one function is $\mathbf V$, and the derivative of the other one is $(\nabla u)^T$. Then you just multiply them by the chain rule.